# How to animate spans inside list items separately

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a list item that is animating from left to right inside a container.

Each item in the list contains two spans and they are animating together.

I can't figure out a **proper way** to put each of the second spans in a container and animate them separately.

So that we have animations for both first and second spans one after another.

simply we should have:

1) At first the first spans (`First Span A:` and `First Span B:`) animate from left to right

2) After the first spans animation end, the second spans animate (`Second Span A` and `Second Span B` ) from left to right. (Each of second spans should have their containers)

```js
//Add Animations
setTimeout(function(){
   list.classList.add("element-animation");
}, 3700)
```

```css
.containerList {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 100vw;
  height: 92vh;
  top: 3vh;
  left:3vw;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

ul#list{
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight:400; 
  font-size: 8.7vh;
  color: #b3a2c7;
  padding-left: 10vh;
  margin-top: 6vh;
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
  top: 15vh;
  left:14vw;  
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li span:nth-child(2) {
 padding-left:3vh;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 color: #ccc1da;
}

ul li:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
}

.element-animation{
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease-out 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  ;
  }
  8% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerList">
<ul id="list">

 <li>
  <span>First Span A:</span>
  <span id="correctState" class="spanList">Second Span A</span>
 </li>

    <li>
  <span>First Span B:</span>
  <span id="positionState" class="spanList">Second Span B</span>
    </li>
 
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't apply the animation to the whole list, but the list items themselves.  After you do that, you can use the `animation-delay` property to delay the animation.

However, since you have `n` number of spans that you want to animate and don't want to write `n` number of delay variations, another way to do it would be to add the class that would do the animation in a staggered way.

This example boils your example down to the most basic.  You can change the order of the `id`s in the `spans` Array if you want to change the order of how they appear.

```js
// Change order of ids to affect appearance order
const spans = [
  "span-first",
  "span-third",
  "span-second",
  "span-fourth"
].map(el => document.getElementById(el));

async function $timeout(duration = 1000) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

(async function() {
  spans.forEach(el => el.classList.add("fade-right--pre"));

  for (const span of spans) {
    span.classList.add("fade-right--during");
    await $timeout();
    span.classList.add("fade-right--post");
  }
}());
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.fade-right--pre {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}

.fade-right--during {
  animation: fadeRightAnim 5s ease-out;
}

.fade-right--post {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

@keyframes fadeRightAnim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span id="span-first">First Span A:</span>
    <span id="span-second">Second Span A</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span id="span-third">First Span B:</span>
    <span id="span-fourth">Second Span B</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..plus one...I think a misunderstanding happened here!  Please have another look at the question...

Comment: @SaraRee I'm not sure I see the misunderstanding.  From my reading, you wanted the list items to animate in in a staggered way.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I want to animate `First Span A` and `First Span B` animation first...

Comment: Then I want to animate `Second Span A` and `Second Span B` animation ...

Comment: You could create separate containers for each of the second spans, but that wouldn't be the proper way maybe!